# Should questions that are asking for an install guide be flagged?

Tags: discussion, scope, tutorials

I have seen many questions that are asking "How to install / upgrade". There are many tutorials out there, so they obviously haven't bothered to do much research - they've just asked over here straight away.

<s>I will reference [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486317/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-14-04), they don't have a problem installing it, they simply want a tutorial.</s>

I will reference [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486848/installation-help) (other has been closed and I don't have a screenshot of it).

Image, for when it is closed:

[image]

Should this be flagged and or downvoted or answered?

Comment: Can someone provide a screenshot of the question for reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That one question fits the definition of too broad, you will need to write the equivalent of a book to start answering the question. Also, I would downvote it, it doesn't show any research effort, and it's unclear. Seriously, there's just too much wrong with that question that isn't worth anyones effort.

Comment: On meta, acceptance really doesn't mean much except to say I agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

Forward them to the one how to install question a lot of them are forwarded to. And downvote. Or don't.

Answer (score -1):

The question looks like posted by a person who has no knowledge of Ubuntu. He/She was trying to install Ubuntu on a windows machine and the question is the genuine one that comes to the mind of a person who have no idea of what to do next. And most people fail to find a correct answer on-line first time when they try.